# Add user to session and get it in an entity using spring

Tags: java, spring, jersey-2.0

I am using spring & jersey2 to serve some rest-requests like:

```
@GET
@Path("/someservice")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public String getSomeStuff(...) {
    login(...);
    // ...
}
```

During a rest-request, I get an authorized user of the rest-request.

Now I need this user while updating or creating entities like:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class PersistentObject {

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void onSaveOrUpdate() {
        setCreationUser(...); // How to get the user of this session?
    }

    // ...

}
```

How can I get the current user of the rest-request there?

Comment: Personally I recommend to use something like Spring Security, but I acknowledge this is too vague to write an answer. If you *really* want something simpler, I guess you could do it with HTTP sessions, `ThreadLocal`s or whatever

Comment: @gpeche I have taken (a longer) look on spring security, but I did not find an approach to do what I need, because I need no authentication for URIs or something like that. Do you have a link to an tutorial or some starting point? TIA!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to perform your login operation (for appropriate resource methods) in a [ContainerRequestFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) and set [SecurityContext](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html):

```
@Provider
public class SecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException {
        final Principal user = login(...);

        context.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContext() {

            public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
                return user;
            }

            // Other methods omitted.
        });
    }
}
```

Make sure you have [jersey-spring3](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html) module on your class-path and the Jersey-Spring integration allows you to inject `SecurityContext` into a Spring service:

```
@Service
public MySpringService implements MyService {

    @Context
    private SecurityContext context;

    public String doStuff() {
        final Principal user = context.getUserPrincipal();

        // ...
    }
}
```

You can't do this if the service, you want to use user principal in, is neither managed by Jersey nor Spring.

Comment: +1 very simple answer, as long as the limitations can be avoided

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security might be useful to you in two ways:

1. It can manage authentication, (you would not need to do that `login(...)` call yourself, it would be done automatically by Spring Security filter chain. But you can still do it manually if you want.
2. Once a request has been authenticated, as long as the request is alive you can access the authenticated user from anywhere just by doing:

`Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getSecurityContext().getAuthentication();
    // auth is an object that holds the authenticated user's data`

I think you *need* some sort of authentication by the fact that you make a `login(...)` and you want to audit the user afterwards. You might not nedd an *authentication form*, but you do need authentication. Spring Security is not only for interactive applications, you can set up an authentication filter that does authentication based on cookies, request parameters, client certificates or whatever, all of that without user interaction.

Furthermore, Spring Security is very extensible, if you have your authentication method already implemented, integrating with Spring Security is easy. And it is also flexible: you don't need to use the security filter chain if it is too heavyweight for your use case. You can do most things manually and use just a little bit of Spring Security if you want.

I *really* suggest you take a deeper look at Spring docs about:

[Spring Security core components overview](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html#d0e1543) and [Spring Security authentication overview](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html#tech-intro-authentication)

I think with just that you will be able to get something working.